# Kendo ui grid - The same Custom validation rule is not working for multiple fields when using custom add / edit popup form template

Tags: jquery, validation, kendo-ui, customvalidator, kendo-validator

I am using custom template for Grid Add/Edit popup form.

Here is my [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/p2xnxqf9/).

In my popup form, I have two Post code fields having named `postcode1` and `postcode2` and both need to be validated using a **custom validator rule** `postalCode`.

**Now the problem is, if I apply the same custom validation rule `postalCode` on both the fields, then the validation works only for the input field `postcode2` and the validation for the input field `postcode1` stops working.**

However, for the input field `postcode2`, if I change the custom validation rule name from `postalCode` to `postalCode2`, the validation starts working for both the fields.

From this I got to know that when using the same custom validation rule on muliple fields cause issues.

So does anyone know how can I create a custom validation rule that can be applied to multiple fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Below is the code from my js fiddle demo:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="popup_editor_template">
    <div>
    <h4>In Post Code fields, enter value length less than or greater than 4 to see custom validation error message for postcode</h4>
    Address 1 : <input type="text" name="address1" required/> <br/>
    Post code 1 : <input type="number" name="postcode1" required                                                data-postalCode-msg="Postal Code must be four digits"
/> <br/><br/>
    Address 2 : <input type="text" name="address2" required/> </br>
    Post code 2 : <input type="number" name="postcode2" required
                                        data-postalCode-msg="Postal Code must be four digits"
                    /> <br/>
  </div>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
function validatePostalCode(input)
{
    //if ( input.is("[data-customPostalCode]") && input.val() )
  if (input.val() )
  {
    console.log("in validatePostalCode: ", input.attr('name'), input.val(), input.val().length);

    //if (input.val().length != 4)
    if( input.val().length != 4 || ( /\D/.test(input.val()) ) )
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },       
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
            fields: {
              postcode1: {
                type: "number",
                defaultValue: null,
                validation: {
                  postalCode: function (input) {
                    console.log('in heree');
                    if (input.is("[name=postcode1]"))
                    {
                      return validatePostalCode(input);
                    }
                    return true;
                  }
                }
              },

              postcode2: {
                type: "number",
                defaultValue: null,
                validation: {
                    //when changing rule name from "postalCode" to "postalCode2", the validation starts working on both fields
                  postalCode: function (input) {
                    console.log('in heree toooo');
                    if (input.is("[name=postcode2]"))
                    {
                      return validatePostalCode(input);
                    }
                    return true;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    },
    },
    height: 800,    
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        "OrderID",
        "Freight",        
        "ShipName",                            
        "ShipCity"        
    ],
    toolbar: [
      { name: "create" },
    ],
    editable : {
      mode: 'popup',
      template: kendo.template($('#popup_editor_template').html())
    },
    save: function(e) {
        alert('Now save');
      e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, I scrapped the idea using validation inside `model` fields. Instead I used `Kendo Validator` and attached the form validator to the popup form.

Here is my [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/p2xnxqf9/2/)

Below is my code from the DEMO:

**JS:**

```
var validator;

function validatePostalCode(input)
{
  if (input.val() )
  {
    //console.log("in validatePostalCode: ", input.attr('name'), input.val(), input.val().length);

    //if (input.val().length != 4)
    if( input.val().length != 4 || ( /\D/.test(input.val()) ) )
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },       
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
    },
    height: 800,    
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        "OrderID",
        "Freight",        
        "ShipName",                            
        "ShipCity"        
    ],
    toolbar: [
      { name: "create" },
    ],
    editable : {
      mode: 'popup',
      template: kendo.template($('#popup_editor_template').html())
    },
    edit: function(e) {
        validator = $("#myform").kendoValidator({
         rules: {
           postalCode: function (input) {
             //console.log('in heree1234');
             if (input.is("[name=postcode1]"))
             {
               return validatePostalCode(input);
             }
             if (input.is("[name=postcode2]"))
             {
               return validatePostalCode(input);
             }
             return true;
           }
         }
    }).data("kendoValidator");
    },
    save: function(e) {
        if (! validator.validate() )
      {
        alert('Form has some errors, so form submit is prevented');
        //var errors = validator.errors();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else
      {
            alert('Form validated successfully. Now save the form data');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="popup_editor_template">
    <div>
    <h4>In Post Code fields, enter value length less than or greater than 4 to see custom validation error message for postcode</h4>
    <div id="myform">
    Address 1 : <input type="text" name="address1" required/> <br/>
    Post code 1 : <input type="number" name="postcode1" required                                                data-postalCode-msg="Postal Code must be four digits"
/> <br/><br/>
    Address 2 : <input type="text" name="address2" required/> </br>
    Post code 2 : <input type="number" name="postcode2" required
                                        data-postalCode-msg="Postal Code must be four digits"
                    /> <br/>
                    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```